# Changing Style of the braces

Tags: java, arraylist, file-io, printwriter

Hello I'm suppose to write a program that changes the Java program
from next-line brace style to the end-of-line brace style like this

public class Test

```
{

     public static void main(String [] args)

    {


    if (expr)

    {

    }
}
```

**To this**

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String [] args) {

    if (expr) {

    }

}
```

the program should read in from the user (prompt them with "Enter filename: ")
the name of the file containing the program to change. If the file cannot be
opened, print an error message to the user (”Bad filename”) and prompt
them again to enter the file name and the modified file should be written back to the same file that you read
from. You cannot have the file open for reading at the same time it is open
for writing. So you should store the lines that you want to write to the file
in an ArrayList of Strings, and then write them to the file after you’ve
closed the Scanner object that you used to read the file

This is what I wrote so far, and I am running into errors. Can anyone help,
Thank you

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class Extension {

    public static void main(String[] args){
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      String fileName = "";
      System.out.println("Enter File Name: ");
      fileName = input.next();
      File f = new File("src/" + fileName);
      do{
       if(f.exists()){

               }
        else{
        System.out.println("Bad filename");
        System.out.println("Enter File Name: ");
        fileName = input.nextLine();
     }

    } while (!(f.exists()));

    ArrayList<String> fileRead = new ArrayList<String>();
    String paran = ("{");
    String newLine = "";
    while(input.hasNextLine()) {
    fileRead.add(input.nextLine());
   }
    input.close();
    f.close;
    //File f = new File("src/"+ fileName);

   PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(f);
   output.print(fileRead.get(0)) ;
   for(int i = 1; i < fileRead.size()-1 ; i++){
      if(fileRead.get(i).equals("{")){
      newLine = fileRead.get(i-1);
      newLine += paran;
    }
    else
     output.print(fileRead.get(i)); 
   }



   }

}
```

Comment: Would this look for any curly brace in the file, or just ones that have a specific meaning to the Java compiler?  If the latter, you'd have to really understand the context of what you're parsing.  That is no trivial task.

Comment: no just the curly brace that has a specific meaning to the complier and change it to next line style

Comment: Any reason you wouldn't be able to use the existing formatter of your-ide-of-choice?

Comment: This looks to me like a classic simple coding challenge set by a teacher - in which case, I would expect that the context of the braces is not important.

Comment: we are suppose to use eclipse, and just change the braces that are significant to the complier

Comment: Why? Any IDE can do this. You've been given a seriously difficult and pointless assignment.

Comment: I wrote some code for this problem but it doesn't work properly. It just runs into errors. Any help is very appericated

Answer (score 1):

> I'm suppose to write a program that changes the Java program from next-line brace style to the end-of-line brace style

This is an idea what you can do:

1. Read from the Java file line by line
2. Store current line of code into a list (as required by your requirements)
3. If current line is empty (newline character or only contains white space), `emptyLine++;`
4. Continue until you hit a non-empty line.
5. If now, you hit a line which does not begins with `{`, add `n` number of newlines to the list where `n equals value of emptyLine` then add that non-empty line. `emptyLine = 0;`
6. Else if you hit a line which is `{`, remove the last newline character from your previously added string from your list and add the current line of code into the list directly (without adding all the newlines you counted just now). `emptyLine = 0;`
7. Continue the process until you reach end of file.
8. Close the file scanner and write it back into the file according to your list.

You can create some helper methods to help you, for example:

```
public boolean isEmptyLine(String text){
    //Return true if text only contains whitespace, tabs & newline
}
```

> I have no clue where to start and I'm very confused and I don't know how to use Text I/o any thing can help me at this point

I would advise you do some practice on reading and writing to a file first.

Comment: Yeah, I'm wondering the same thing :-( Your answer is much more comprehensive than mine and looks like it would work. Have one upvote from me :-)

Comment: I wrote some code for this problem but it running into errors ;( can you check it out. Anything can help

Comment: @MelDavid Hi, I would suggest you to open a new question to ask about your codes. Editing your question will deny all the answers here which is supposed to address your previous issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use regular expression matching to do this.

This should sort out any open brace following parentheses:

```
String outputString = inputString.replaceAll("\)\s*\{", ") {");
```

I'm too tired right now to figure out how to match the open brace after the class declaration, but it it should be possible with a regular expression.

Comment: I've re-read this this morning and realised that using regular expressions is pretty weak. There are too many edge cases where it won't work (like strings that contain curly braces). This is a very challenging problem comparable with creating your own compiler :-(

Comment: Thanks - you didn't have to :-) My solution was a bit pants in retrospect. Regular expressions are great, but probably not the right way to go here. I guess that's the danger of perusing Stack Overflow when tired.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Java I/O classes, specifically File, BufferedReader and InputStreamReader. You can read from the console by putting a BufferedReader on System.in, like so:

```
BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

Then you can simply use

```
String input = stdIn.readLine();
```

There are readers and writers for files as well. Take a look at FileInputStream for example! Maybe [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) can also help you.

As for the "Bad filename" error, this can be done by catching Exceptions.

```
try {
    File inputFile = new File(filename);
}
catch (Exception e) {   // You replace this catch by any kind of exception, e.g. an IOException. You can add as many catches as necessary. A modern IDE or your compiler will tell you that you forgot to catch a specific Exception as well.
    System.out.println("Bad filename");
}
```

Take a look at [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) lesson from Oracle.

To see if the current line only contains a brace, a good start might be to check this:

```
String tmp = currentLine.trim();
if (tmp.equals("{")) {
    // Do what you have to do with opening braces
} else if (tmp.equals("}")) {
    // Do what you have to do with closing braces
}
```

The Stack data structure can help you with appending to previous lines. It is a LIFO structure, just as your everyday stack. You can use myStack.pop() to get the previous line of code. You could put a while-loop around that to keep popping until you get a non-empty-or-whitespace line of code:

```
String lastLine;
while ((lastLine = myStack.pop()).trim().equals(""))
    continue;
lastLine.append(" {");
```

(This is just an example)

Comment: I implimented some of that in my code that put above, but im running into errors can you help me with that

Comment: Which errors are you getting? Your for-loop will not result in the desired output. Is that what you mean? This is what I meant with using a Stack: you can manipulate the code before starting to write to your output file. Use a Stack instead of an ArrayList and modify your code during the reading: when you see a "{", pop until you get the desired line of code, append the "{" to it and put the result back on the stack.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: Syntax error, insert "VariableDeclarators" to complete LocalVariableDeclaration close cannot be resolved or is not a field Duplicate local variable f at Extension.main(Extension.java:35)

Comment: That's the problem that I am getting

Comment: replace "f.close;" by "f.close();"

Comment: I did that and I got this error 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 The method close() is undefined for the type File
 Duplicate local variable f

 at Extension.main(Extension.java:35)

Comment: There are some logical issues as well, such as "fileName = input.nextLine();", I think you mean "f = new File("src/" + input.nextLine());". But try to get your code to compile first, you can debug those errors later.

Comment: It appears File doesn't have a close() method, which isn't a surprise since you don't open a File. You open a Stream to a File. You closed that Stream so that is sufficient.